# WooCommerce, continue payment go directly to pay. Skip pay for order

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

Click on the 'continue to payment' on the checkout, is redirected to pay for the order. Stripe payment pop-up only comes up after clicking on 'place order'.

I want to skip the 'place order' page. So 'continue to payment' should open the stripe payment pop-up.

How do I do this? Which hook should I use?

Thanks
[image]
[image]